# What is the "closed volume integral" used for?

Tags: integration, notation, terminology, volume

What I mean by "closed volume integral" is the symbol $\unicode{x2230}$ notated by \oiiint in latex {which does not show up here}.

I did some searching on this topic and found out that there is no such thing as an open or closed volume in 3D which makes no sense to me as the volume of a sphere for example is closed but the volume of a hemisphere can be considered open as it is bounded by the hemisphere's boundary.
I also tried to find some formulas where the closed volume integral would appear and I only found this equation on wikipedia which I have never seen before https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Oiiint $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \unicode{x2230}_\Omega \frac{\partial F}{\partial s} d\Sigma$$
Lastly I saw in a reddit post that the symbol can be used for generalising the divergence theorem in 4D.

Can someone explain the use of this symbol to me?

Comment: You can get the $\large \unicode{x2230}$ symbol using `\unicode{2230}` but I don't know scaleable it is: $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\large \unicode{x2230}_\Omega \frac{\partial F}{\partial s}\;d\Sigma$$

Comment: Firstly, you are integrating with respect to 3 variables, or integrating in 3 dimensions (hence over a volume). As with a contour integral $\oint$ where you are integrating over a path e.g. a circle in the complex domain, and a surface integral where you are integrating over 2D elements, in a closed volume integral you are integrating wrt a volume and in the same way that: $$\oiint\limits_S \mathbb{F}\,d\mathbb{S}=\iiint\limits_V\nabla\cdot\mathbb{F}\,d\mathbb{V}$$ we may say: $$o\iiint\limits_V\mathbb{F}\,d\mathbb{V}=\iint\iint_{V_h}\nabla\cdot\mathbb{F}d\,\mathbb{V_h}$$

Comment: in terms of getting the symbol in mathjax the best I've gotten is trying to use \rlap or \stackrel like: $$\rlap{\huge\,\,O}{\iiint}$$

Comment: @PeterPhipps `\unicode{2230}` gives $\unicode{2230}$ (Arabic like character). What did you type in?

Comment: As an aside,`\iiint\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\Huge{\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(90deg)}{\hphantom{r}0}}}` gives $${\iiint\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\Huge{\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(90deg)}{\hphantom{r}0}}}$$

Comment: @ТymaGaidash٠, I typed in `\unicode{x2230}` with an x before the 2230 and the x got lost somewhere. I apologise.

Comment: @PeterPhipps  Yeah thats the symbol I edited my question to include it thank you.

Comment: @HenryLee So basically the divergence theorem in 4D. However if there is no such thing as an open volume in 3D the $\unicode{x2230}$ symbol is useless as we can use $\iiint$ for everything.

Comment: Looks like it's for an integral over a closed (=compact and without boundary) 3-manifold. Although at that point people usually just use $\int$.